# Mapbox Rotating Marker by GeoJSON

Tags: ajax, maps, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I have just started using mapbox and i have some troubles with it.

I have added angle to my geojson data in order to rotate the image to a specified angle from geojson, but I'm having trouble with writing its rotate function :(

we are acquiring our data from AJAX so the function should be compatible with AJAX.

Any help would deeply appreciated.

This is my geojson data:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-79.00, 40] }, "properties": { "title": "Big astronaut","id":"100", "icon": { "iconUrl": "_vehicle.png", "iconSize": [32, 32], "iconAnchor": [50, 50], "popupAnchor": [0, -55], "className": "dot", "angle":"87" } } }
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate marker in Leaflet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494649/rotate-marker-in-leaflet)

Comment: I recommend the [Leaflet.RotatedMarker plugin](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker)