# Importing module that extends a class

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, node-modules

While looking for a way to rotate markers in [leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/), I found the module [leaflet-rotatedmarker](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker). I installed it via npm, but now I don't know how to actually use it.

As per the readme, it only extends the existing `Marker` class. To my understanding, I should be able to just call `Marker.setRotationAngle()` now, but that function does not exist. Importing `Marker` from `leaflet-rotatedmarker` does not work either.

How do I properly import the extended class or how do I extend the existing leaflet class with the functions/attributes in the module? Thanks.

I am talking about the `import { XYZ } from 'leaflet-rotatedmarker'` statement.

**Edit:**

It also does not work if I try to set the `rotationAngle` in the constructor:

```
const marker = L.marker([tmpAgv.Pos.X, tmpAgv.Pos.Y], { alt: tmpAgv.Id }, {rotationAngle: 180}).addTo(this.mapObject);
```

The marker is still not rotated.

Comment: `setRotationAngle()` is not a static class to access it like `Marker.setRotationAngle()`. Create instance of marker and then use it.

Comment: I know, that was just an example. I have an instance and I'm trying to call the function, like in the example on the github page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I installed the same package you have:

```
npm install leaflet-rotatedmarker
```

And import it:

```
import 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';
```

And this is how I used:

```
let m = L.marker([lat,lng]).addTo(this.map);
m.setRotationAngle(180);
```

And before and after results:

[image: Before Leaflet]

After:

[image: Leaflet After]

Comment: Thank you so much! The import statement was what I did wrong! Thanks for the help!