# How to dynamically move and rotate marker in react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have wrote a React project with `react-leaflet` and hook. My goal is to move and rotate marker every second. However, moving part is working fine. But the rotation of marker is not working. I am really stuck for last few days. I couldn't find a good solution. Please help me.

The map component is as follows.

```js
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-marker-rotation';

const MySimpleMap = () => {
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(22.899397);
  const [lon, setLon] = useState(89.508279);
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(30)

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      myfun();
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [lat]);

  const defaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
    iconSize: [20, 40],
    iconAnchor: [18, 18],
    popupAnchor: [0, -10],
    shadowAnchor: [10, 10]
  }); 

  const myfun = () => {    
    setLat(lat + 0.00001);
    setLon(lon + 0.00001);
    setHeading(heading+5);
    console.log("angle:" + heading);
  };
  return (
    <MapContainer className="map" center={[lat, lon]} zoom={21}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={[lat, lon]} icon={defaultIcon} rotationAngle={heading} rotationOrigin="center">
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default MySimpleMap;
```

The complete problem is in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wood-kgv4p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have also created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-wood-kgv4p?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some of the provided answers for rotating markers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494649/rotate-marker-in-leaflet) , was able to get it to work with your provided codesandbox. The default `Marker` component does not have `rotationAngle` or `rotationOrigin` as valid props, you'd need to do something like done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60579518/6682929) to get that. So instead we can use re-use the rotation code and plug it into your code by lifting it into a re-usable function:

```
const applyRotation = (marker, _options) => {
  const oldIE = L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM === "msTransform";
  const options = Object.assign(_options, { rotationOrigin: "center" });
  const { rotationAngle, rotationOrigin } = options;

  if (rotationAngle && marker) {
    marker._icon.style[L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM + "Origin"] = rotationOrigin;

    if (oldIE) {
      // for IE 9, use the 2D rotation
      marker._icon.style[L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM] = `rotate(${rotationAngle} deg)`;
    } else {
      // for modern browsers, prefer the 3D accelerated version
      marker._icon.style[
        L.DomUtil.TRANSFORM
      ] += ` rotateZ(${rotationAngle}deg)`;
    }
  }
};
```

And then calling it once the rotation has been changed with a `useEffect` because we also want the `Markers` position to be updated otherwise the rotation won't work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    applyRotation(markerRef.current, { rotationAngle: heading + 5 });
  }, [heading]);
```

When you call `myFunc` it updates the position (lat,lon) as well as the header (rotation) so by placing it in the useEffect, on next render `Marker` should have updated its position.

I have a codebox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-kepler-g50xe?file=/src/MySimpleMap.js).

The above solution does have some issue's you'll need to sift through the `leaflet-rotatedmarker` library to get those missing edge cases. However if you can add that library a better solution would be importing that:

```
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-rotatedmarker";
```

and using the extended `setRotationAngle` instead.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (markerRef.current) {
      markerRef.current.setRotationAngle(heading);
    }
  }, [heading]);
```

You can also use that to lift it into a `RotatedMarker` component so that your original use case of the props `rotationAngle={heading} rotationOrigin="center"` will work:

```
const RotatedMarker = forwardRef(({ children, ...props }, forwardRef) => {
  const markerRef = useRef();

  const { rotationAngle, rotationOrigin } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    const marker = markerRef.current;
    if (marker) {
      marker.setRotationAngle(rotationAngle);
      marker.setRotationOrigin(rotationOrigin);
    }
  }, [rotationAngle, rotationOrigin]);

  return (
    <Marker
      ref={(ref) => {
        markerRef.current = ref;
        if (forwardRef) {
          forwardRef.current = ref;
        }
      }}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </Marker>
  );
});
```

Here's the codepen where i tested the [above out](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-curran-yfil5?file=/src/MySimpleMap.js)

Comment: thank you for your excellent fix to the code. Do you have any idea why the marker in your code starts from the zero degree to the desired angle in each update? Therefore, it's giving a vibration is each cycle instead of smooth rotation. What could be the fix to that?

Comment: Yea its because the code is missing the initial rotation setting, specifically the `initHook` for the marker -> https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker/blob/master/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js#L8 , I tried to go with minimal things from the library but you might as well use it or move over those implementation details that I missed. Updated answer above with how that would work if you did just use the lib

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan, you saved my job... if you could explain how the forwardRef works here that'd be great, because the code obviously works, but I can't understand it. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: “Regular function or class components don’t receive the ref argument, and ref is not available in props either.” - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html. using forwardRef just lets you use the prop “ref” on your components. Used it here so that `RotatedMarker` could be a wrapper component for `Marker` where it adds support for the props “rotationAngle” and “rotationOrigin”.

Comment: I was able to get it working based on this answer. "leaflet": "^1.7.1", "leaflet-rotatedmarker": "^0.2.0", "react-leaflet": "^3.2.5",

In particular the RotatedMarker component worked great after importing "leaflet-rotatedmarker";